# How to retrieve data from nested list in Python

Tags: python

I have a nested list:

```
product = {
    'Name': ['Small Pizza', 'Medium Pizza', 'Large Pizza'],
    'Price': [5, 8, 12]
}
```

How can I retreive it as following?

```
1. Small Pizza  : 5
2. Medium Pizza : 8
3. Large Pizza  : 12
```

Comment: `print(dict(zip(product["Name"], product["Price"])))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
product={'Name': ['Small Pizza', 'Medium Pizza', 'Large Pizza'], 'Price': [5, 8, 12]}

for i in range(0,len(product['Name'])):
    print("{}. {} :{}".format(i,product['Name'][i], product['Price'][i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach....If you need it sorted by price.

**Demo:**

```
product={'Name': ['Small Pizza', 'Medium Pizza', 'Large Pizza'], 'Price': [5, 8, 12]}

d = dict(zip(product["Name"], product["Price"]))
c = 1
for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print("{}. {} : {}".format(c, k, v) )
    c += 1
```

**Output:**

```
1. Small Pizza : 5
2. Medium Pizza : 8
3. Large Pizza : 12
```